# access denied to PHP from Blackberry 10 platform using phonegap - closed

Tags: php, javascript, cordova, blackberry-10

I have a problem with my phonegap project working on blackberry simulator. The version is 10.

When I say phonegap, I haven't used any Cordova features yet but my simple javascript functions are not working in the first place.

I have a button click which invokes a Javascript function. This JS function has a PHP as URL to retrieve data. Following is the function code -

```
function getAllDetails() {
  var myTable = '';
    myTable += '<table id="myTable" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 border=1>';
    myTable += "<tr><td><b>S.No.</b></td><td><b>Full Name</b></td><td><b>DOB</b></td><td><b>Gender</b></td><td><b>Address</b></td><td><b>Image</b></td><td><b>Video</b></td></tr>";
    var url = "http://XXX.XXX.XX.XX:XX/PG_crud_experiment1/retrieve_all.php";
    $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
                $.each(json, function(i, v) {
                    alert(v.id);
                            myTable += "<tr><td>" + v.id + "</td><td>"
                                    + v.name + "</td><td>" + v.dob
                                    + "</td><td>" + v.address + "</td><td>"
                                    + v.image + "</td></tr>";
                        });

                $("#emp_tb1").html(myTable);
            });
};
```

The problem here is my button click is entering the Javascript function but I am getting an error saying it cannot access the URL where my PHP file is placed. The PHP is actually running a SELECT SQL and retrieving values from a database.

Below is a screenshot of my error on BB 10 simulator.

Can anyone please tell me why this problem is coming up? Are there any pre-requisites/procedures to be followed before the device can run some Javascript functions or to access the PHP scripts on server?XXX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to edit the config.xml file of the project -
add the tag  `<access subdomains="true" uri="http://*URI name here*"/>`. Only then, Blackberry allows access permissions to a different domain.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a cross-site request issue - I'm suspecting that the PHP side doesn't accept requests from outside of its own domain.

How about putting this header at the top of your PHP file?

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply... It's working on android platform. Could it be specific to Blackberry?

Answer (score 0):

As **anami** said earlier you need to have cross domain origin enabled in your server php file. Also you need to have `<access subdomains="true" uri="http://*URI name here*"/>` in config.xml for blackberry.

Having both of these in place should solve your issue.