# Javascript alert - access to php not allowed? - Closed

Tags: php, javascript, android, blackberry

When I am trying to call a .php file from my Javascript function, it simply says

> `"Access to http://192.168.0.104:89/someDir/filename.php is not allowed"`

.

This scenario is coming on my blackberry emulator, as the app is built with phonegap, HTML and Javascript.
The same script worked great on my android emulator. just fails on blackberry.

Can anyone please help me where the fault is?

Comment: anybody here who can help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to edit the config.xml file of the project - add the tag 
`<access subdomains="true" uri="http://*URI name here*"/>`.

Only then, Blackberry allows access permissions to a different domain.

Comment: I think this is the same problem asked here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605461/access-denied-to-php-from-blackberry-10-platform-using-phonegap, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588561/phonegap-build-for-blackberry-is-throwing-a-javascript-error by you. You can always edit and update your question, you don't need to replicate your question. And if your question is solved then marked it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Not and expert with JS but just a thought, could you just call your JS from PHP? And then include your PHP files in that file?

```
<?php include("php/file.php"); ?>
<script src="js/file.php"></script>
```

Not ever sure if this is what you're trying to do though.

Comment: no this is not what I am looking for. thanks for ur time answering.